# failure during clear cash using symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

i'm new to symfony i tried to install package `admin panel` by command `composer require admin` but it gives me error `The deprecation template must contain the “% service_id%” placeholder`, i executed command composer update, and found some answer ( Updating easycorp/easyadmin-bundle, Updating doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle, Updating symfony/orm-pack) I tried these command but it gives me error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of ContainerLTFhDJN\EntityManager_9a5be93::getProxyInitializer() must be compatible with ProxyManager\Proxy\LazyLoadingInterface::getProxyInitializer(): ?Closure in D:
\wamp\www\symfony4\var\cache\dev\ContainerLTFhDJN\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 5876
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError^ {#33
  -error: array:4 [
    "type" => 64
    "message" => "Declaration of ContainerLTFhDJN\EntityManager_9a5be93::getProxyInitializer() must be compatible with ProxyManager\Proxy\LazyLoadingInterface::getProxyInitializer(): ?Closure"
    "file" => "D:\wamp\www\symfony4\var\cache\dev\ContainerLTFhDJN\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php"
    "line" => 5876
  ]
  #message: "Compile Error: Declaration of ContainerLTFhDJN\EntityManager_9a5be93::getProxyInitializer() must be compatible with ProxyManager\Proxy\LazyLoadingInterface::getProxyInitializer():
 ?Closure"
  #code: 0
  #file: "D:\wamp\www\symfony4\var\cache\dev\ContainerLTFhDJN\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php"
  #line: 5876
}
```

Comment: try update with dependencies `composer update easycorp/easyadmin-bundle --with-dependencies`

Comment: Since it seems that even composer commands fail, what you can do is to remove the package (this should not make composer crash), then simply require it again with the option ```--update-with-dependencies```. If it still fails, remove the package again and try to require it again, this time with ```--update-with-all-dependencies```. If it still fails, wait for another answer or call an exorcist ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem after updating some doctrine package. Removing `var/cache` fixed it for me.